# Visual Studio 2010: pattern based search replace other than regex?

Tags: regex, windows, unix, cygwin, replace

I've taken over a project that is full of code like this:

```
if (aTraceUserids[t].Trim().ToUpper() == Userid().Trim().ToUpper())
{
    // ...
}
```

What is - using tool-assisted expression formulation - a good way to do a search replace into something like this on a case by case base:

```
if (aTraceUserids[t].Equals(Userid(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    // ...
}
```

**Edit** (thanks Dave for making me think on this further):

I know this should be possible with [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but those are hard to get right and document, so I wonder about tool assisted ways that help me both phrase the expressions and execute them.

Ideally I'm looking for a pattern based search/replace tool that allows me to

- enter the search/replace patterns
- enter the patterns for the files and directory names to match
- visually assists me with the search/replace matches, and allows me to post-edit each occurrence

I don't care much which platform as these kinds of search/replace actions will likely apply to other big code bases as well.

So: any solution based on *nix, Windows or web are fine. CygWin and/or WINE based solutions are fine too. (That's why I removed the VS2010 tag and added some platform tags).

Comment: If you want pattern based replacement with as much force as regex, you're going to have to use some sort of programming language. I hear python is nice this time of year.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, as it made me think further. I probably want less force than regex. But I do want visual support for the search/replace occurrences so I choose by hand which ones I do replace and maybe even modify. I'll edit my question based on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this was originally tagged with 'Visual Studio', Visual Studio itself can do regular-expression based find/replace, and the standard 'Find and Replace' dialog will let you pick and choose by hitting 'Find Next', 'Replace' or 'Replace All' as you choose.

For example, I recently changed an API from;

```
Log.Error(string message, bool someotherArg);
```

to

Log.Error(string message);

And easily used Visual Studio to replace all usage throughout my codebase of this modified API like so;

Find what;
    Log.Error({.*}, true);

Replace with:
    Log.Error(\1);

The backquote in the replace line `\1` puts the grouped regex contained by `{...}` into that spot in the replace.

Handy, and built-in. Works for me.